# UISearchbar not changing the tint

Tags: uisearchdisplaycontroller, ios7.1

I have added a `UISearchDisplayController` into my storyboard. And I changed my statusbar tint colour into clear. But when I run the app still status bar shows in default way. Then I changed in `ViewDidAppear` like this

`

```
  - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
        {
           self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.placeholder = @"Search by location";
           [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setTranslucent:NO];
           self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.barTintColor=[UIColor clearColor];


          [super viewDidAppear:YES];
        }
```

`

This place holder can visible when run the app,, but colour is not changing. What is the reason for this and how can I solve this problem? Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Here is a relevant thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941395/setting-tint-color-for-embedded-uisearchbar-in-navigation-bar